# StartApp iOS banner won't show with my correct devID

Tags: banner, startapp

I integrated StartApp banner to my iOS app. The banner showed correctly for a while on both simulator and devices. But one day the banner 
Stop showing without changing the code.

I figure out that banner would show if I use an INCORRECT devID. And won't show with my actual devID.

The banner even shows with any strings but my real devID.

Is the something wrong with my account? I still can access my StartApp account. Nothing makes me think that my account has any restriction of displaying ads.

Thanks,
-Khang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent an email to StartApp support, and they told me that my account has been suspended due to my app is generating automated and deceptive impressions, clicks, installs and/or other actions with respect to StartApp ads.

Be careful, we should not be cheating. :)

Cheers

-Khang

Comment: My StartApp account has been suspended too. Now what should I do to continue working with StartApp?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing you can continue with except you use a totally different account. see the quote

"We would like to bring to your attention that your account was suspended and the is the reason that your application is not active with your Dev Id.
You will not be able to claim any revenue generated later than this date, any attempt to create a new account in our system will be blocked automatically. Since it has been flagged with your information"